# administer wordpress despite 406 blocks from modsecurity

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-security2

I would like to adapt the administration urls of my wordpress site so that they work with modsecurity rules. Indeed, I use a waf which manages incoming traffic. Modsecurity is installed on waff. Also, I don't have access to this waf, just to my back server. I use apache

Answer (score 0):

CRS dev-on-duty here. You're probably talking about [OWASP Core Rule Set](https://coreruleset.org) rules. This ruleset is often used for ModSecurity WAFs.
The Core Rule Set offers a Wordpress exclusion package that should help you fight with false positives. You can activate this exclusion package in your [crs-setup.conf](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.3/master/crs-setup.conf.example#L361).

However, a blocked request is normally not blocked with an HTTP status 406, but with a HTTP status 403. So it's probably not the WAF that raises your error.

I'd like to support you find out if it's the WAF that blocks you, but unfortunately, you did not include enough information for us to actually help you.

Please provide the following if possible:

- Full alert message (ideally send us the full audit log of the request)
- Web server and version or the platform you are using
- ModSecurity version
- CRS version

ATTENTION: When submitting logs, please remove all personal information like IP addresses, hostnames, passwords, etc.
We'll be happy to have a look afterwards. CRS dev-on-duty.

Comment: hello, please excuse me for my late reply. Indeed it is the waf rules that block my wordpress site. However, I don't have access to the waf, only my server admin can provide the modsecurity version. I would like to either put a rule on my back server to avoid false positives or better be able to administer my wordpress site on the intranet (without going through the internet to avoid being blocked by the waf).