# Python to WordPress REST API remote posting 406 error even I'm passing user agent in the header

Tags: python, wordpress-rest-api, mod-security, http-status-code-406

The following codes are used to post on WordPress site remotely.
This is a python script to post on WordPress remotely.
It's working on other websites.
But sometimes, I'm facing issues.
What should I do when I get 406 error code?

```
import base64
import requests
import json

# Authenticate
user = 'wp_user_name'
password = 'gikI 1g3Q cl4Q z6qG dzcs 12345'
url = 'https://sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2'
token = base64.standard_b64encode((user + ':' + password).encode('utf-8'))
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
                        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
wp_title = "This is Sample Title"
slug = "this-is-sample-url"
status = 'publish'
content = '<p>This is sample paragraph</p>'

post = {'title': wp_title,
        'slug': slug,
        'status': status,
        'content': content,
        'categories': '1',
        'author': '1',
        'format': 'standard',

        }
r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=headers, json=post)
print(r)
```

Comment: It's not enough info to solve your problem. Do you see any ModSecurity related lines in log?

Comment: Also please note, that may be this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264472/administer-wordpress-despite-406-blocks-from-modsecurity